# Insert into table.. exec at linked server does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This works, returning a resultset :

```
exec ('select ''col'', count(1) from test.dbo.[Table1] with (nolock)') at svrA
```

When I try to insert the resultset into a table:

```
insert into rowcount_sub (tablename,rowcnt)
exec ('select ''col'', count(1) from test.dbo.[Table1] with (nolock)') at svrA
```

Fails giving this error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "svrA" returned message "No transaction is active.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "svrA" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Comment: May it have sth with MSDTC (Microsft Distributed Transaction Coordinator) service? you can start it on services.msc

Comment: Is this MSDTC on the remote server or the local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The operation could not be performed
>   because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10"
>   for linked server "svrA" was unable to
>   begin a distributed transaction.

The message is pretty clear and quite explicit. All you have to do is open your system documentation and follow the steps on configuring distributed transactions: [Configuring MS DTC Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753866%28WS.10%29.aspx).

There are also plenty of blogs and tutorials out there:

- [How to configure DTC on Windows 2003](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2003/)
- [How to configure DTC on Windows 2008](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2008/)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve the same problem by using OPENQUERY instead of EXEC:

```
insert into rowcount_sub (tablename,rowcnt)
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(svrA, 'select ''col'', count(1) from test.dbo.[Table1] with (nolock)')
```

Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 6):

If you do not use distributed transaction on purpose, You can use advanced properties of the linked server object on main server to disable promotion of distributed transaction.

[image: Disable promotion of distributed transaction]

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction" from True to false fixed my issue.