# Create new table with results from EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to take the results of an `EXEC` query and put them into a table in my SQL Server 2017 database.

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked before like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973330/create-new-table-from-query-results), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973330/create-new-table-from-query-results), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395003/dynamic-equivalent-of-insert-into-using-exec?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I have not found a solution that works.

The `EXEC` query runs great on its own, and results in exactly the data I am looking for:

```
-- EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'OLAP', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'code'
EXEC (@sqlcode) AT OLAP
```

I cannot use `OPENQUERY` due to the SQL exceeding the 8000 character limit.

Attempt 1:

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'sqlcode'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
truncate table [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
insert into [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

But get:

> Cannot find the object "purchases" because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions.

Attempt 2:

```
SELECT * INTO [jerry].[dbo].[purchases] FROM OPENROWSET('EXEC (@sqlcode) AT OLAP')
```

but get an error of

> Incorrect syntax near ')'`.

Attempt 3

```
CREATE TABLE [jerry].[dbo].[purchases] ([Transaction_Date] DATE,    [Requirement_Date] DATE, [Element] NVARCHAR(256), [Trx_Quantity]    NVARCHAR(256), [Part_Number] NVARCHAR(256), [NHA_Part_Number]    NVARCHAR(256), [Group] NVARCHAR(256), [Details] NVARCHAR(256));    INSERT INTO [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]    EXEC (@sqlcode) AT OLAP
```

but get an error of:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" returned
>   message "Unable to enlist in the transaction.". Msg 7391, Level 16,
>   State 2, Line 208 The operation could not be performed because OLE DB
>   provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OLAP" was unable to
>   begin a distributed transaction.

Attempt 4

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'sql'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[report]
CREATE TABLE [jerry].[dbo].[report] ([Transaction_Date] DATE, [Requirement_Date] DATE, [Element] NVARCHAR(256), [Trx_Quantity] NVARCHAR(256), [Part_Number] NVARCHAR(256), [NHA_Part_Number] NVARCHAR(256), [Group] NVARCHAR(256), [Details] NVARCHAR(256));
insert into [jerry].[dbo].[report]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

But I get an error of:

> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 209 The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server
>   "OLAP" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
>   And, when I try to change the "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions being set to False" per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999906/distributed-transaction-error), I get another permission's error.

In short, I just need the results of the first `EXEC` query entered in to a SQL Server database. The `EXEC` query does hit an external Oracle database to which I have ONLY read permissions and cannot change any security settings.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `INSERT INTO... EXEC....` is the correct syntax ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6d3a870985b4aa900d4c44b4382bc23)), which suggests you don't have access to insert into `[jerry].[dbo].[purchases]`, or it doesn't exist (as the error suggests)

Comment: Can you post the EXEC?  I'm no genius, but isn't EXEC used for Stored Procedures and not Views?

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]` followed by `truncate table [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]`. How you you `TRUNCATE` a table you just dropped or `INSERT INTO` it? For a `TRUNCATE` or `INSERT INTO` statement to work the table needs to exist...

Comment: I cannot post the `EXEC` @JohnnyBones. Unfortunately it is proprietary company owned SQL. I can confirm the contents of the `EXEC` query execute just fine, and even when I use Oracle's SQL Developer to run just that SQL code against the Oracle instance that too works great.

Comment: @Larnu I am not sure. I am very new to SQL Server, so this is has been a tidal wave in the last 24 hours. I'm sure I'm making an error, but I don't understand how. Judging from other posts on SO, it seems other users have shared in my sadness.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, you can't do anything to a table without it existing. Remove the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]` and this will work. What you're doing it like deleting a file, and then trying to edit it. You can't edit the file anymore, it's been deleted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is on the `TRUNCATE` statement in the one with the correct syntax. HAd the OP looked at the line number the error occurred in (which isn't in their post), I think they would have noticed that, @SeanLange :)

Comment: I will try your suggestions and see what I can find. I have tried to research every error I have come across, as evidenced by the multiple tags to other posts and attempts.

Comment: I'm not mocking you at all, @JerryM. nor am i assuming. I'm very confident the reason for the error is because you `DROP` the table first. We can, however, test this [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb9e9e8b2c6e1ebd03194b15c680488f). I've excluded the `INSERT...EXEC` statement, however, note you get the same error you had (proving it isn't the `INSERT` that was the problem). If we, however, omit the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, statement, everything works as planned: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2d87eab5a5fb267841205cd3b5fe8cd2)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I am not sure if you feel comfortable to post as an answer @Larnu. I have tried your suggestion, but I get the same error as attempt 4, regarding an an inability to begin a distributed type transaction

Comment: We're onto a different error the, in truth. The problem i was pointing out was more of a typographical error; so I'm fine with leaving it in the comments. You might, in truth, be better off focusing on the first (corrected) query and asking about that again and deleting this one; as the initial error has clouded the error.

Comment: I think now you are hitting problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360467/insert-into-table-exec-at-linked-server-does-not-work. Set option 'remote proc transaction promotion' to 'false'. sysadmin will have to change it.

Comment: Hi @Piotr if you look at the bottom remark, I have followed those suggestions but am unable to change any settings as I am low-level permissions user. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Other option is to enable distributed transactions, which is more complicated and requires configuring MSDTC service. I would advice to ask your admin to change transaction promotion. Other question is if you can use SSIS or other tools to do this transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, particularly from @Larnu

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'sqlcode'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
truncate table [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
insert into [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

Was nearly correct, but needed to be switched to

```
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'sqlcode'

truncate table [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
insert into [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at OLAP
```

Since I could not *drop* a table and then perform any operation on it without recreating it.